# Best method for rebind jQuery UI Sortable from another module on DOM change after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-events

I have a side js module which make lists sortable by jQuery UI Sortable. But Main script use ajax update of content, new lists can arrives.

I cannot use callbacks from ajax directly to bind UI Sortable from my js module. I think about events listening. Is it right way in my situation?

For example, for clicks I can simply use `$('#change_container').on('click', '.dynamic_list', function(){...}`

But how about Sortable after **DOM change**? Which event i have to use? I heard about `DOMSubtreeModified`. Or may be `$(document).ajaxSuccess` event?

Or is it more specific way for UI Sortable dynamic binding?

On rebinding I plan to use something like this:

```
$('.mylist').sortable('destroy');
$('.mylist').unbind();
$('.mylist').sortable(options);
```

Comment: `unbind()` not works if event is not binded by `bind()`.